# How to add application icon in notification tray?

Tags: android, notifications, tray

I understand that it's possible. At least I see that various applications used to put in notification tray their icons (e.g. Skype).

What about my application? What should I do to put my icon or message in notification bar?

Comment: Please only do this if you have a concrete reason to do so (e.g., you are notifying them of some background event, you are using `startForeground()` to deliver continuous value from a service). Do not raise a `Notification` just for grins.

Comment: For desktop newbs like me, "tray icon" == "status bar":

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly to use Notification.Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391870/how-exactly-to-use-notification-builder)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

> You specify the UI information and actions for a notification in a [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) object. To create the notification itself, you call [`NotificationCompat.Builder.build()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#build()), which returns a [`Notification`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) object containing your specifications. To issue the notification, you pass the [`Notification`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) object to the system by calling [`NotificationManager.notify()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))...

Answer (score 2):

This is the code to put notification message in notification tray.100% working.

```
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

          Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndActivity.class);          
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        // build notification
        // the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
        Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("My message")
                .setContentText("Subject")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.MyApplogo)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(""+msg.get(3))).build();
              //  .addAction(R.drawable.line, "", pIntent).build();
        n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
         notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Comment: @My pleasure. you can upvote the app if it is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great example to display the notification.

[Notification Demo](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html)